# Scrolling in Y axis Problem in Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two tabs from bootstrap

The problem is the tabs are not scrolling in y after 100vh

Means When I start Scrolling it stuck.

I have a 100 datas a day in the website but.
This is irritating me a lot and I am getting data from my table.

Means The Tabs are seriously not scrolling after 100vh.

I have tried a lot but nothing worked.

*Here is my code*

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Entries</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Contact's</a>

  </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab" >
    
            <table class="table table-striped my-5">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Image</th>
                    <th scope="col">Time</th>
                    <th scope="col">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
                    <?php

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY id DESC";


                    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                    $index = 1;

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

                        $id = $row['id'];
                        $name = $row['Name'];
                        $email = $row['Email'];
                        $img = $row['Img'];
                        $time = $row['time'];

                        echo '
                        <tr>
      <th scope="row">'.$index.'</th>
      <td>'.$name.'</td>
      <td>'.$email.'</td>
      <td><a href="../../'.$img.'">Image</a></td>
      <td>'.$time.'</td>
      <td>
      
      <div class="row">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="deleteEntry('.$id.')"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-2" onclick="makeWinner('.$id.')"><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
      ';

                        $index++;
                    }
                    ?>
                

            </tbody>
        </table>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
    
    <div class="container">
        
        
        <table class="table table-striped my-5">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Msg</th>
                    <th scope="col">Time</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    
                        <?php

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Contact` ORDER BY id DESC";


                    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                    $index = 1;

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

                        $id = $row['contact_id'];
                        $name = $row['contacter_name'];
                        $email = $row['contacter_email'];
                        $msg = $row['contact_message'];
                        $time = $row['contact_dt_time'];

                        echo '
                        <tr>
      <th scope="row">'.$index.'</th>
      <td>'.$name.'</td>
      <td>'.$email.'</td>
      <td>'.$msg.'</td>
      <td>'.$time.'</td>

      </tr>
      ';

                        $index++;
                    }
                    ?>
                        </tbody>
        </table>
                
    </div>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `overflow-y: scroll;` on the Tab that you want. It will make the content scrollable on the y-axis.